# Creating longitudinal profile of stream out of river system in QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, dem, profile

I have been using 'profile tool plug-in' in QGIS 3.20.1 to visualise longitudinal profile of the river in QGIS. Selection options, i.e. temporary polyline; and selected layer, are working well. **However, using the selected polyline option is not showing any result.**

[image: tool]

I have attached the screenshot. Selected line is visible in yellow colour. When I created this selected feature a layer, then the tool is making the profile by the option-selected layer.

How can I get longitudinal profile of each line in a shapefile in QGIS?

Comment: QGIS 3.26 [June 2022] has this built in now. See https://youtu.be/pZmrw_zR7sA?t=655 and you can create profiles interactively.

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz I updated QGIS 3.26 and tried the elevation profile tool but it is not giving the correct result. ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-FhJUOUhSFgeerPXXJb-CnZiztUbuQzE/view?usp=sharing ). As you can see in the image, the same line has been select for both the elevation tool and the profile tool, but I am having different results. To verify the result, I selected a random point on the line and identify tool showed the result 2643m which is matching with the result of profile tool. Kindly let me know how to overcome this problem.

Comment: @Mapperz how to reduce the distance between the sample points in elevation profile tool.